# Show view controller from main storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, case

I have a `case` in one of my Swift files which runs the following method:

```
     case .editProfile:
        vc = PoiDetailViewController()
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(vc,animated: true)
```

It doesn't seem to work when I run the code.

The view controller is located on the main storyboard and I would like `PoiDetailViewController` to display when this case is called.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more .? what are you trying to say.?

Comment: popViewController and popToViewController and its variants do not "pop up" a view controller. It means pop view controllers off the stack until you reach the specified view controller. You need to call pushViewController or presentViewController.

Comment: so this should work without using segues? @Tim

Comment: I've tidied up your question a bit so it's easier to understand. So essentially, you're looking to navigate to `PoiDetailViewController` if the case is `.editProfile`?

Comment: YES @Super_Simon

Comment: I have provided you with an answer, I hope that is what you're looking for. No segues are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you should be able to achieve what you're looking for by `present` in your code. Like so:

```
  case .editProfile:
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PoiDetailViewController") // or whatever identifier you have given it
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That should work, however, make sure you set a storyboard ID for your view controller in the identity inspector.

**No segues are required.**

To set up a storyboard ID click on the View Controller you would like to use (in this case, `PoiDetailViewController`) and click the identity inspector icon and set a storyboard ID where it asks. I have attached an image so you can see where it needs to go (in the field marked 'Storyboard ID')

[image: Identity inspector]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT @Super_Simon   reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x10be73cf0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier poiDetailViewController''
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: That's because you haven't added the identifier like I told you to. I have added a screenshot of where it needs to go. Set the storyboard ID and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As per my Understanding you need to pop to specific View Controller if it is in stack and if not then you need to push to that controller

```
var loginVCFound:Bool = false;

    let navigationController : UINavigationController! = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController;
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

    let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = navigationController.viewControllers
    for aViewController in viewControllers {
        if aViewController is LoginVC {// Pass the name of your controller here
            loginVCFound = true;
            navigationController.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
            break;
        }
    }
    if !loginVCFound { // change the identifier and VC with yours
        let objLoginVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
        navigationController.pushViewController(objLoginVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: This could be simplified, if you find the LoginVC, just pop and return, otherwise push the view controller. You don't need loginVCFound.